# Visual Studio 2019 don't recognize ASCII characters

Tags: c, visual-studio, ascii

i have a problem with ASCII characters. I have assignment to make a ASCII table in C using ASCII characters. For a test i wrote such a programm:

```
{
    int i;

    /* Print ASCII values from 32 to 255 */
    for(i=32; i<=255; i++) 
    {
        printf("ASCII value of character %c = %d\n", i, i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It works, but it show only ASCII characters from 32 to 127 (7 bit), after that it don't show anything...
All 8-bit-ASCII are just ignore by compiler. 
So my question is - how can i encode extended ASCII characters in VS 2019?

Comment: Technically [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is a *seven* bit encoding. And perhaps the problem with the "extended ASCII" is that it has the high bit set which have a different meaning if the output window expects UTF-8 encoded output?

Comment: What is `i`?  Please post a **complete** example.

Comment: It depends on the output device (not the compiler), how extended ASCII is treated. It's non-standard.

Comment: "just ignore by compiler" - I think the compiler doesn't care at all. Your _terminal_, on the other hand, is responsible for actually displaying the characters.

Comment: Try using `%lc`.

Comment: It could be that your terminal is set up to use Unicode (UTF-8), in which case, all the characters from 0x80..0xFF are either wholly invalid (0xC0, 0xC1, 0xF5..0xFF) or need to be combined with others in particular multicharacter sequences.  Since you're using MSVS, that might not be the problem — I don't know what is normal on Windows.  But on a Linux system, it might easily be a factor.  Your printing code would never produce a valid UTF-8 sequence for values from 0x80 upwards.